# trying to remove char from str in list; getting assertion error

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, char

no idea what an "assertion error" even is, but i'm trying to run this through my class test module and getting the following error:

File "/var/gt_test_envs/iVpgS6thyOoxSD9V/wrk/homeworkTests.py", line 201, in test_remove_char
self.assertEqual(expected, returned)
AssertionError: ['pZlp', 'Bn', 'GaFu', 'sMopFKjxl', 'IZhhtE'] != None

code is below:

```
    def remove_char(str_list: object, char: object)-> object:
str_list = ()
char = []
for value in char:
    str_list = str_list.replace(value, '')
    return object
```

Comment: The test `assert`s that the `expected` list is equal to what your function returned.  If the two things aren't equal, it raises the error, failing the test.

Comment: oh ok, so simply it's saying that my code is returning the incorrect string. thanks for the clarification - this one has me stumped!

Comment: My advice is to write out and test your function one line at a time so you can understand what exactly each line is doing.  It looks like you're currently trying things completely at random by combining words and symbols you've seen in other code without understanding their meanings -- it's possible to eventually get a working program by randomly guessing what the "right answer" is, but only for very very small functions, and even then it takes a while!

Answer (score 2):

The `AssertionError` is being raised because your function returns the wrong result, and the test `assert`s that it returns the right result (this is how unit tests usually work).  According to the error message, it's expected to return a list of strings but instead it returns `None` (that is, it's not just returning the wrong result, but entirely the wrong type of object).

There are a **lot** of bugs piled on top of each other in order to produce this result -- I don't think a single line of this function is doing what you want it to do.  I'll do my best to explain all the bugs individually.

The indentation of your code snippet is completely mangled; the entire body of the function must be indented (unindenting indicates that the function is over).  I'd expect a completely empty function body to produce an IndentationError, so the code that you're actually running the test on must be different from what you pasted into your question above.  If the entire body of the function were indented two more levels it would run and would return `None` (as seen in the test failure message) so I assume that's what you're actually working with.

The type annotations are technically valid but not useful; typing something as an `object` is pretty much like not having type annotations.  The main purpose of type annotations is to help you (and others) understand how the code works; it goes without saying that everything is an `object`, so annotating everything that way doesn't add any understanding.  If you can say more specifically that `str_list` is a `list`, and `char` is a `str`, and the function returns another `list`, it's easier to understand what the function is doing and how it works.  If you can be a little **more** specific and say that it's a `List[str]` (a list of strings) that's even more helpful!

Starting your function by reassigning `str_list` and `char` to empty values (overwriting the parameters) ensures that it's impossible to return a valid result.  Note also that you're assigning a `tuple` to `str_list`, and a `list` to `char`.

Even if the loop that follows were able to build the correct result as `str_list`, you're returning `object` instead of `str_list`, so the caller is receiving the "object" *type* rather than the actual `str_list` object (which should be a list but is actually a tuple).

On top of that, since the return is happening inside the loop body (which is never executed because you're iterating over an empty tuple, which happens because you overwrote `str_list` right at the start), it never actually happens, which is why the function returns `None`.

Here's a working (and correctly typed) version of the function:

```
from typing import List

def remove_char(str_list: List[str], char: str) -> List[str]:
    new_list: List[str] = []
    for value in str_list:
        new_value = value.replace(char, '')
        new_list.append(new_value)
    return new_list
```

Note that we're building an entirely new list (rather than modifying the original `str_list`), and doing the `replace` on the individual `value`s from the list (which we get by iterating in a `for` loop over `str_list`), not the list itself.

Here is a simpler version of the same function; this does almost exactly the same thing as the above code, but as a list comprehension statement:

```
from typing import List

def remove_char(str_list: List[str], char: str) -> List[str]:
    return [value.replace(char, '') for value in str_list]
```

As I said in the comments, my advice for the future is to read and write your code carefully, one line at a time -- don't write a line of code if you don't know exactly what it does and have a reason for wanting it to do that exact thing.  It is very difficult to find bugs in a program if you don't know what each line of code is doing.  If you can't figure out how to do a particular thing, ask your teacher for help with that particular thing rather than writing a broken program and then trying to get someone else to rewrite it for you.  It'll work some of the time (like it did this time), but it's not likely to get you all the way through your programming class.

Good luck!